# Is there a way we can overrides a specific controller or change some variables using bootstrap in ZEND?

Tags: zend-framework, bootstrapping

I don't know if I am thinking wrong or right. Just Correct me or give me suggestions.

Like the question for security reasons I want to change some variables in controller using bootstrap like I want to validate a license and if the license is not valid then perform some actions using bootstrap? I do not want to use any code in controller directly but I am wondering How can I do that? What do you think How can I do it? Without writing the code in controllers I can se a specific variable wrong and then it will generating errors, something like this?

Comment: What kind of variables you want to change? POST/GET/Zend_Registry/other global data is possible to check/change, but not local variables ofc.

Comment: There are [`plugins`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) that have the `predDispatch()` method or `dispatchLoopStartup()` methods that are called before any controllers. Maybe it will respond to your need.

Answer (score 2):

You can add [plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) so it will be executed after bootstrap but before Controller (better to do this here than bootstrap).

Add to application.ini:

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "MyScripts"
resources.frontController.plugins.Test = "MyScripts_Controller_Plugin_Test"
```

and file:

```
class MyScripts_Controller_Plugin_Test extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {

public function routeStartup($request) {
  //$request has what you probably need
}
```